# Searching functionality returns ArgumentNullException when compiled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I try to compile my code then ArgumentNullException error occurs on 'Where' clause. I think I'm doing everything well on this. Do I need any start value (in ActionResult parameter)?

**Controller:**

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

       private IDocuments _docs;

       public ActionResult Index(string custNr)
        {
            var docsModel = _docs.GetAll();
            var model = docsModel
                                   .Where(w => w.docsModel.ACCOUNT.Contains(custNr) || custNr == null) //here shows me an error
                                   .Select(s => new DocumentsModel
                                   {
                                       Company = s.docsModel.COMPANY,
                                       CustName = s.docsModel.NAME,
                                       Account = s.docsModel.ACCOUNT.Trim(),

                                   })
                                          .OrderBy(o => o.DATE);
            return View(model);
        }
```

**View:**

```
        <th>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                <p>
                    Name: @Html.TextBox("custNr")
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                </p>
            }
        </th>
```

Need to add that in Account column is populated with values, has no nulls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should help to invert your OR-Expression:

```
.Where(w => custNr == null || w.docsModel.ACCOUNT.Contains(custNr) )
```

An OR-Clause always gets evaluated from left to right. The way you did it, it will first execute the `Contains` function and afterwards will check if the input parameter is null.

The other way around the `Contains`-function will not be called if the argument is null as the first OR-clause is fulfilled and it will not execute the second one.

`Contains` on a string should never be called with null as input parameter.

[MsDoc about string.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Contains_System_String_):

> Exceptions

> ArgumentNullException

> value is null.